# Is it obvious intuitively that $1^p + 2^p + \cdots (n-1)^p$ is a polynomial in $n$?

Tags: intuition, bernoulli-numbers, bernoulli-polynomials

I am reading about Bernoulli function in "Calculus vol.1" by Matsusaburo Fujiwara(in Japanese).

The author proved that $$1^p + 2^p + \cdots (n-1)^p$$ is a polynomial in $n$   of degree $p+1$.

I understood the proof. In fact, it was an easy proof.

But I am not sure that it is obvious intuitively that $$1^p + 2^p + \cdots (n-1)^p$$ is a polynomial in $n$ or not.

The fact that the number of terms depends on $n$ is of concern to me. Notice also that the final sum is of degree $p+1$, not of degree $p$, and I would like an argument that accounts for that.

Comment: What's the difference between something having "an easy proof" and being "obvious intuitively"?

Comment: Are you worried about it the $n$s canceling out?

Comment: Are you worried about the fact that the number of terms you are summing depends on $n$?

Comment: @AlexanderGruber Thank you for your comment. I am not worried about it.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC Thank  you for your comment. I am worried about it.

Comment: @tchappyha: I have edited your question to add that concern, and hopefully make your concerns more obvious to other readers. Please do reject my edit if you think it not appropriate for your question.

Answer (score 1):

This may be viewed as the consequence of the fact that the forward difference operator

$$ \Delta f(x) := f(x+1) - f(x) $$

maps a polynomial of degree $p$ into another polynomial of degree $p-1$. This observation itself is a direct consequence of the binomial theorem. Then your sum is kind of a reversal of this process, so it is not strange to expect that the sum $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^{p-1}$ results in a polynomial in $n$ of degree $p$.

A similar line of reasoning applies, in a neater way, to integration and differentiation. Indeed,

$$ \int x^{p-1} \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{x^p}{p} + C $$

for $p$ positive integer follows from the differentiation rule

$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x} x^p = px^{p-1} $$

which itself is again a consequence of the binomial theorem.

Answer (score 0):

It is an obvious inductive (with respect to $p$) corollary of the binomial formula .

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you think the proof is not "obvious intuitively".  The $\ldots$ are hard because they are not part of the system of what works and what doesn't.  Expand it a little more $1^p+2^p+3^p+\ldots (n-2)^p+(n-1)^p$ and I think it is easy to see that if you do the full expansion that there is no term with a higher exponent than $n^p$, so it is a polynomial.

Added based on the edit:  If the coefficient of the $n^p$ term grows with $n$, that becomes an $n^{p+1}$ term.  That is still polynomial.  The point is that it doesn't become exponential, which is a totally different order of growth.

Comment: Are you sure your argument is complete? You have to account for the final sum being of degree $n+1$, not $n$.

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC:  that doesn't matter.  Both are polynomials.  But each term is of order $p$ (not $n$).  It is true that the coefficient of the $n^p$ term has a factor  of order $n$ so you can consider it to be of order $n^{p+1}$.

Comment: I mean, I get the argument you want to make, and I'm trying to figure out how to make it precise, but when you say "the co-efficient of $n^p$ has a factor of $n$ in it", don't you have to prove that the co-efficient isn't of order $n^2$? Intuitively it shouldn't, because there are only $n$ terms, but we're both waving our hands here.

Comment: I don't understand the question because each term does not have an $n$ in it, but you are adding up $n$ terms.  That is where the $n$ comes from.

Comment: Would you say the same thing about adding up the $n$ terms 1 + 4 + 9 + ... + $n^2$?

Comment: Absolutely.  There are $n$ terms, each less than (or equal to) $n^2$, so the sum is less than $n^3$.  No problem.  That is a good example of what I am saying.  In fact the sum is about $\frac 13n^3$, but we don't care about the coefficient here.

Comment: You are making an argument for bounding growth. The question says it is exactly a polynomial. Those look to be different things to me. (We seem to be taking different slants on this problem and probably shouldn't be filling up the comments with this. I'll just let this be my last comment.)

Comment: @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC:  the question itself is contradictory.  It accept that an expression is a polynomial in $n$ of degree $p+1$.  That is enough to say it is polynomial in $n$.  I was hoping to help with the "obvious intuitively".  It appears I have failed, but I think "obvious intuitively" is not well defined.  I have downvoted the question because I think it misses the point entirely.

Comment: Ah, we are taking different approaches. I agree that it's intuitively obvious, but I'm trying to write it up fairly formally and having a heck of a time doing so. Hopefully your argument will help the O.P.

Answer (score -1):

What seems true to me is "the sum of $n$ polynomials, $q_i(n)$, with degree($q_i) \le p$, is a polynomial in $n$ of degree at most $p+1$".

If I can prove this, then letting $q_i(n) = (n-i)^p$ we would have you statement (with the summation term written in the opposite order).

Comment: I don’t think that satisfies the question. There is only one polynomial.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: rewrote to clarify in light of your comment.